# Unity: ArgumentException: Getting control 1's position in a group with only 1 controls when doing repaint Aborting

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Начал разбираться с кастомным интерфейсом свойств инспектора, так как стандартный перестал устраивать и написал свой кастомный **PropertyDrawer**, всё хорошо до первого **Play**, после нажатия на него ловлю ошибку:

```
ArgumentException: Getting control 1's position in a group with only 1 controls when doing repaint
Aborting
UnityEngine.GUILayoutGroup.GetNext () (at <9ff04fda545c4aacb8dab659ad40b2f4>:0)
UnityEngine.GUILayoutUtility.BeginLayoutGroup (UnityEngine.GUIStyle style, UnityEngine.GUILayoutOption[] options, System.Type layoutType) (at <9ff04fda545c4aacb8dab659ad40b2f4>:0)
UnityEditor.EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal (UnityEngine.GUIContent content, UnityEngine.GUIStyle style, UnityEngine.GUILayoutOption[] options) (at <4f969f18b6984883abf0f762caf9325d>:0)
UnityEditor.EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal (UnityEngine.GUILayoutOption[] options) (at <4f969f18b6984883abf0f762caf9325d>:0)
Source.HealthDrawer.OnGUI (UnityEngine.Rect position, UnityEditor.SerializedProperty property, UnityEngine.GUIContent label) (at Assets/Editor/HealthDrawer.cs:16)
UnityEditor.PropertyDrawer.OnGUISafe (UnityEngine.Rect position, UnityEditor.SerializedProperty property, UnityEngine.GUIContent label) (at <4f969f18b6984883abf0f762caf9325d>:0)
UnityEditor.PropertyHandler.OnGUI (UnityEngine.Rect position, UnityEditor.SerializedProperty property, UnityEngine.GUIContent label, System.Boolean includeChildren, UnityEngine.Rect visibleArea) (at <4f969f18b6984883abf0f762caf9325d>:0)
UnityEditor.GenericInspector.OnOptimizedInspectorGUI (UnityEngine.Rect contentRect) (at <4f969f18b6984883abf0f762caf9325d>:0)
UnityEditor.UIElements.InspectorElement+<>c__DisplayClass59_0.<CreateIMGUIInspectorFromEditor>b__0 () (at <a122028f8c314654ad750c3d9eb1f725>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

И пропадает мой кастомный **PropertyDrawer** с инспектора и не появляется до тех пор, пока не сохраню класс с пустым **OnGUI** и заново не вставлю код с моим **OnGUI**

HealthDrawer.cs

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

namespace Source
{
    [CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(Health))]
    public class HealthDrawer : PropertyDrawer
    {
        public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
        {
            SerializedProperty currentHealth = property.FindPropertyRelative("m_currentHealth");
            SerializedProperty maxHealth = property.FindPropertyRelative("m_maxHealth");
            SerializedProperty minHealth = property.FindPropertyRelative("m_minHealth");

            EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
            {
                EditorGUILayout.PrefixLabel(label);
                GUILayout.Label("Current: ");
                currentHealth.floatValue = EditorGUILayout.Slider(currentHealth.floatValue, minHealth.floatValue, maxHealth.floatValue);
            }
            EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();

            EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
            {
                EditorGUILayout.PrefixLabel(" ");
                GUILayout.Label("Min: ");
                minHealth.floatValue = EditorGUILayout.FloatField(minHealth.floatValue);
                GUILayout.Label("Max: ");
                maxHealth.floatValue = EditorGUILayout.FloatField(maxHealth.floatValue);
                currentHealth.floatValue = Mathf.Clamp(currentHealth.floatValue, minHealth.floatValue, maxHealth.floatValue);
            }
            EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: `#if UNITY_EDITOR` и `#endif` быть не должно. Скрипты для редактора должны находиться в папке с именем `Editor` и их контент не попадает в билд. Таких папок может быть много, не одна.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Работоспособность этого кода хоть в каком-то виде - случайность. [`PropertyDrawer` не поддерживает `GUILayout` методы](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PropertyDrawer.html).

> Note that for performance reasons, EditorGUILayout functions are not usable with PropertyDrawers.

Старая IMGUI система признана устаревшей, на ее смену пришла UIElements, которая все еще находится в раннем доступе, но, когда-нибудь ее релизнут.

---

Если очень хочется сделать через `PropertyDrawer`: на этапе отрисовки в ваш метод передается прямоугольник `Rect position`, в рамках которого вы и должны рисовать.

Comment: Какие люди! А как же токсичное сообщество? Я тут тружусь на очередной бан в поте лица.

Comment: @Yaroslav я не буду ничего обсуждать, аккаунт восстановлен для англоязычного SO.

Comment: Так он ещё таксичней, там 90% вопросов с тегом `unity3d` заминусованные.  Хотя задающие вопросы в 100 раз приветливее и культурнее русских.

Comment: @Yaroslav я не ради unity туда иду ;)